# NFC Tags - way to controll tag scan time

Tags: android, nfc

I was wondering, if it would be possible to program NFC tag in way, that it would report someone scanning it with timestamp.

Let's say someone has to be at certain place (with NFC tag) at certain time.

Is there a way, with NFC, to verify if someone was at this place at certain time?

And preferably, so he/she cannot copy tag. Or tag has any "hashing" function etc?

Verification with Android device/soft? :)

Looking for something similar to *KOSguard MINI* but with NFC

Comment: Here is my [idea](https://pastebin.com/TgWwdx80) about what I understood from your requirement, please elaborate your requirement more if I was getting wrong...

Comment: It's more like I was wondering if it's possible to implement NFC Tag to return something like:
`$t = time(); return md5(SALT . $t) . $t;`
And of cource SALT is not readable.